# Jackson отдает только часть объекта

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

Добрый день!
Есть проблема, использую библиотеку Jackson для работы с JSON, при получении списка объектов, часть из них получаю заполненными не до конца, т.е. от сущности берется только поле id, а остальные игнорируются. Т.е. остальные поля не null, они просто не сериализуются.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dolgnost", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@EntityListeners(DefaultListener.class)
public class Dolgnost implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "iddolgnost", nullable = false)
private Integer iddolgnost;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "naim_dolgnost", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String naimDolgnost;

@Column(name = "vus", length = 20)
private String vus;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "nomer_pp", nullable = false)
private int nomerPp;

@JoinColumn(name = "id_zvanie_cat", referencedColumnName = "idzvanie_cat")
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private ZvanieCat idZvanieCat;
```

И вложенный объект:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "zvanie_cat",  schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,    property = "idzvanieCat", scope = ZvanieCat.class)
public class ZvanieCat implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "idzvanie_cat", nullable = false)
private Integer idzvanieCat;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "naim_zvanie", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String naimZvanie;
@Column(name = "kateg_vsl", length = 45)
private String kategVsl;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idZvanieCat")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<PensionRazmer> pensionRazmerSet;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idzvanieCat")
private Set<ZvaniePoluch> zvaniePoluchSet;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "idZvanieCat")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Dolgnost> dolgnostSet;
@JoinColumn(name = "id_poluch_cat", referencedColumnName = "idpoluch_cat", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
private PoluchCat poluchCat;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idZvanieCat")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<ZvanieRazmer> zvanieRazmerSet;
```

Так вот, объект zvanieCat в составе объекта dolgnost приходит не полностью, а только в виде id.

Comment: Сдается мне, это связано с `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`. Вообще, использовать один класс для ORM и для отдачи наружу - скверная затея.

Comment: Как на счёт посмотреть в сторону Gson?

Comment: Проблема была в аннотации
'@JsonIdentityInfo', прошу прощения.